# ffmpeg libav: Any way to set stream info in an input format instead of searching for it?

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I'm writing a player for an RTMP stream using the ffmpeg API.  I know the usual way to get the stream info into an input format is with `avformat_find_stream_info`.  And that works.  However, because it's RTMP it takes a long time for it to scan enough of the stream to pick up the info.  I've played with `max_analyze_duration` and `probesize` and it's a bit better, but it still takes 10-15 seconds to load.  That's way too long for my application.

But I'm the one making the stream on the other end, so I know exactly what's in it.  It seems like it would make more sense for me to *tell* the input format what the stream info is rather than asking it to search for it.  But I can't find any examples of this, and my attempts to use `avformat_new_stream` with an input format aren't working.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  And if so, could you point me in the direction of how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what is known as an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Yes, you can spoof the sequence header (assuming h.264/aac). But it won't accomplish what you want. What is happening is your RTMP server (reflector) is eating the first [GOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures). So even if the analyze was done faster, you must first wait for the first video key frame anyway.

You need to configure your RTMP server to send the full GOP (in nginx+rtmp the setting is `wait_key on`)